# How to join elements within an array of strings?

Tags: python, arrays, string, join

I have this array of strings that I have split element wise so I can do stuff to it. Now I want to return them back into a sentence.

```
my_array = (['T', 'e', 's', 't', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'd', 's', '!'])
```

Is there a way to join them togeter back into a sentence whilst keeping the formatting? Ideal output would be something similar to the following:

```
joined_array = (['Test Words!'])
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```py
my_array = (['T', 'e', 's', 't', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'd', 's', '!'])
joined_array = ''.join(my_array)
```

Which gives:

```py
'Test words!'
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
joined_array = ''.join(my_array)
```